# Spring boot controller how to sanitize user input (request dto) in order to pass a Checkmarx

Tags: java, spring-boot, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding

I have sample Spring boot controller code like followings:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    private final PersonService PersonService;

    public PersonController(PersonService PersonService) {
        this.PersonService = PersonService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/Person", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public PersonResponseDto Person(@Valid @RequestBody PersonRequestDto PersonRequestDto,
                                            @RequestHeader(value = "x-correlation-id", required = false) String correlationId) {

          String something = HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(PersonRequestDto.getSomething());
          PersonRequestDto newRequestDto = PersonRequestDto.builder()
                  .something(something)
                  .date(PersonRequestDto.getDate())
                  .build();
        return PersonService.save(newRequestDto);
    }
}


public class PersonRequestDto {
    @NotBlank
    private String something;

    private LocalDate date;
}
```

Even I did a sanitized on a string field `something`, the checkmarx still complains:

> flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method doSomething

I don't know what's the point or how to sanitized the java `LocalDate` type field and also for XSS requirement there is no need to sanitized field other than string.

Anyone knows how to write code to make checkmarx happy? I know this is frustrated to write some code just let some tool works.

Comment: @0xadecimal well it's not really duplicated, in that one only concern is string type but checkmarx need to sanitized all type of fields.

Comment: ok fair enough. Do you know for certain that it is complaining about the Date ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I tweak the fields one by one and then come up with those.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal adding code just to keep checkmarx happy, however it might not be a bad idea to add some validation to the date field. You could add the NotNull annotation  at a minimum , or if the date represents a persons birthday you could also add @Past ? Maybe that will be enought to keep checkmarx happy.

Comment: Yes I had all those validations stuff but still can't make checkmarx happy.

Comment: as you said, Checkmarx complain about a display in method doSomething. I think that the problem is about how Cx will search for the query and flow. I think (based on my experience on CX and what you said => XSS), you must encode the data in the output. If you post the doSomething method, this could help too

Comment: I suspect a bad implementation of one Checkmarx rules. I notice some other things like this before, and I have to have to add the type to a custome rule for CX.